# angular 5: serializing api calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I wait for an API to complete before sending the same API request again?

I have a form where when the user inputs something I make an API call. When the user updates the input I want to wait until the previous API call finished.

I am using angular 5.

For example, if I have the following and I trigger onClick twice, I want the second call to initiate only after the first one completes.

```
component:
onClick() {
   this.http.post(this.url, payload, options); 
 }
```

How can I use flatMapWithMaxConcurrent to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're simply looking for something like:

```
class MyComponent {
    lastCall: Observable

    onClick() {
        let newCall = this.http.post(url); 

        if (this.lastCall) {
            this.lastCall = this.lastCall.concat(newCall)
        }
        else {
            this.lastCall = newCall
        }

        return this.lastCall
    }
}
```

This keeps track of any previously made calls in the member `lastCall`. The first time the user clicks, it will be null and the method will simply return the result of the post. The second time, however, the method will return the observable that is the result that of performing first the previous call and then the new call. The new call will be performed immediately if the old call has terminated, but otherwise it will wait for the previous one to terminate.

However, I'm not sure this is actually the behavior you are looking for. If the user clicks many times and the backend is slow, there will be lots of calls made one after the other that continue long after the user has stopped clicking.

I think it's more likely you want to keep track of whether a call is already ongoing and, if it is, ignore any further clicks until it has terminated. This would for example prevent the user from accidentally submitting something multiple times if the backend is slow and they click again because the frontend stopped responding.

You can achieve that in the following way:

```
class MyComponent {
  isPosting: boolean

  onClick() {
    if (this.isPosting) {
      return
    }

    this.isPosting = true

    return this.http.post(url)
      .finally(() => this.isPosting = false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your original solution will work for my use-case.  And just for the record, how does this compare with flatMapWithMaxConcurrent?

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the calls is important, you can use concat to merge the two API calls.

const result = callOne.concat(callTwo);

result.subscribe(val=> ...)

Comment: I updated the question. I dont have both the calls available at once, they are available on a user trigger. In the above example I added to my question, how do I use the concatMap operator?